I want to change the default success message of applied coupan by taking a private value in JS object
This success message "Your coupon was successfully applied." should be replaced with coupan label.
I have console.log(totals) value in
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-coupon-code.js

here is portion of my code.
).done(function (response) {
            var deferred;

            if (response) {
                deferred = $.Deferred();
                console.log(totals.totals._lastValue);
                console.log(totals);

and it consist of this hierarchy

I want to get the value of coupon_label, how can i git it?
console.log(totals.totals._lastValue);   ??
console.log(totals.totals.getLastValue());    ??


Did you tried below answer ??
And other thing what is _lastValue in (totals.totals._lastValue); ??
i think its _latestValue not _lastValue

Please try this
console.log(totals.totals._latestValue.extension_attributes.coupon_label);

